# Very basics: How to create & manage lists in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've very recently started looking into Prolog, and while I'm very unfamiliar with it still, so it seems "weird" compared to the other languages I've used before (C#, Java etc), it's also a bit interesting.

As for right now, I've started working with structures/lists. Using the classical example, I figured I'd make some kind of in-memory book database.

The entirety of the code I have thus far is:

```
addBook(title, author, year, company, books):-
append( [title, author, year, company], books ).

findBookByCompany(list, company):-
    member(company, list).

findBookByAuthor(list, author):-
    member(author, list).

findBookByYear(list, year):-
    member(year, list).

?-addBook("Book 1", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1", books).
?-addBook("Book 2", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1", books).
?-addBook("Book 3", "Author 2", 2014, "Company 1", books).
?-addBook("Book 4", "Author 3", 2015, "Company 2", books).
?-addBook("Book 5", "Author 4", 2016, "Company 3", books).

?-findBookByAuthor(books, "Author 1").
?-findBookByYear(books, 2011).
```

Now, does this work? No. But I do know what I'm *trying* to do. I'm trying to utilize the `addBook()` function/predicate to create 5 different books, and store them in a `books` variable. After that, I'm also trying to experiment with checking if said list has books where the Author is `Author 1` , or the year being `2011`.

I'm going to guess this isn't really doing at all what I'm expecting it to, all I really have to go on is the error/warning message I get: `Goal (directive) failed: user:addBook()` , and the same thing for the two find-functions/predicates.

I also realize there are probably safer/more efficient ways of doing this in the first place, but getting hints/pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, using the current solution, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: All variables in Prolog are *immutable*: once you assign a value, it always remains that value. You can not "append" values to a list, you construct a new list that is a copy of an old one, with one element extra.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought the whole concept of append/2 was to be able to take one list, and return it "into" another? Of course this takes for granted `books` (in my example) does not contain data we want to keep?

Comment: @Xariez - If you find yourself calling a Prolog "predicate" a "function" then you should slap yourself hard on the wrist. They are not functions.

Comment: @Xariez - Variables start with capitals. Atoms start with lower-case.

Comment: And use single quotes in place of double quotes in this context.

Comment: Whenever you see "variable" in the context of Prolog, erase that word and replace with "shared blackboard" (stored on the heap, and on which a term, as in `g(X,h(Z))` is inscribed that can be made more precise (constrained) in the places where further blackboards are mentioned (`X` and `Z`) -- but never less precise). BBs are passed between procedures for reading/matching and constraining. I have come to the conclusion that the names "variables" or "logic variables" is just terrible terminology for newcomers.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - The use of "variable" in Prolog matches the use of the word in mathematics. It's pretty much the same. It's just different from how it is used in imperative languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic version of your code that I can come up with is this:

```
book("Book 1", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1").
book("Book 2", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1").
book("Book 3", "Author 2", 2014, "Company 1").
book("Book 4", "Author 3", 2015, "Company 2").
book("Book 5", "Author 4", 2016, "Company 3").

findBookByCompany(Company,Name) :- book(Name,_,_,Company).
findBookByAuthor(Author,Name) :- book(Name,Author,_,_).
findBookByYear(Year,Name) :- book(Name,_,Year,_).

?-findBookByAuthor("Author 1",Name),write(Name),nl,fail.
```

Prolog is about stating facts and rules, and then testing a hypothesis.

You don't build a list of books, you just state facts about books.

If you then want to find out if there is a book from a certain author then you create a rule. For `findBookByAuthor(Author,Name)` to succeed then `book(Name,Author,_,_)` must succeed, and you go from there.

My above program outputs the following:

```
Book 1
Book 2
No.
```

It outputs `No.` because I specifically told it to fail and backtrack to get all answers, but the backtracking will continue until it can't find any more answers and it then reports failure.

---

If you want to write this in a more procedural way, then you can do this:

```
?-
    append([], [book("Book 1", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1")], X1s),
    append(X1s, [book("Book 2", "Author 1", 2012, "Company 1")], X2s),
    append(X2s, [book("Book 3", "Author 2", 2014, "Company 1")], X3s),
    append(X3s, [book("Book 4", "Author 3", 2015, "Company 2")], X4s),
    append(X4s, [book("Book 5", "Author 4", 2016, "Company 3")], X5s),
    member(book(Name,"Author 1",_,_),X5s),
    write(Name),
    nl,
    fail.
```

It's not good Prolog though. You should avoid this.

Comment: Okay, that certainly helps. Also got to show extra respect at the fact that, even if bad prolog, you followed exactly what I asked for. Thanks a lot!